# What does this stamp TAG 46 471 mean?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps

[image]I have been in the UK for the last 4 months (since April 2018). My husband is a dual citizen (British and Australian), and as an Australian citizen, I can stay for 6 months. The reason why I didn't originally enter on a spousal visa is because it takes 3 months, I have to apply from Australia, and I have to hand over my passport (so can't use it for 3 months). I had some family commitments which I needed to attend so was not in a position to apply until later this year (when I could remain in Australia for 3 months without travelling). Every time I enter the UK, I am grilled but I can show a return ticket to Australia, and that I do assignment/contract work remotely (I am not employed in the UK). The last time I entered, I received the following 'tag' stamp and am really nervous about my upcoming travels. I have two, possibly three, trips planned until I finally head home to Australia to apply for the spousal visa. Any advice on what this tag stamp means? Thanks!

Comment: How long are you spending in the UK in total? It sounds like you’re breaching visa-free entry by living in the UK through long periods of time through frequent visits. It’s also forbidden to do paid or unpaid work, including in practice remote work

Comment: Your text reads as though you meant to add an image, but I don't see an image. Did you mean to add an image of the stamp? It might be a good idea to do so.

Comment: Traveller - how am I breaching visa free entry? I have been in the UK for 4 months, and plan to leave in 2 - making it a total of 6 months. That is line with all the leave to enter stamps. Also, I thought the restriction is on 'employment' in the UK, which I am not engaging in. I am an aid worker, and work based on contract - I travel overseas to provide trainings etc. I have been consistent with my facts, and can clearly show a return flight, which is why I was surprised about this particular pen notation.